# Reducing TSP to Hamiltonian circuit

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, np-complete, reduction

How can I convert the (decision version) of the traveling salesman problem to the Hamiltonian circuit problem (i.e. how to reduce TSP to HCP, so that if I have a solution to HCP, then I will use that solution to solve TSP problem)?

Answer (score 6):

Every problem in NP can be polynomial-time reduced to any NP-complete problem - that is what makes the NP-complete problems so important.

Here's a chain of reductions:

1. Vertex Cover can be reduced to Hamiltonian Circuit.
2. 3-SAT can be reduced to Vertex Cover.
3. Satisfiability can be reduced to 3-SAT.
4. Any decision problem in NP can be reduced to Satisfiability (Cook-Levin theorem)

TSP is a problem in NP, so it can be reduced, in ridiculously long polynomial time, to Hamiltonian Circuit.

I got the reductions from [Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716710455)

Comment: TSP is not a decision problem, so it's not in NP.

Comment: @fons There is a decision problem formulation of TSP, given in the book I referenced. Avoiding mathematical notation, the decision problem is whether there is a tour of all the cities with total weight no greater than a given bound.

Comment: I am aware there is, but then you probably meant "The TSP decision problem is in NP so ..." 

Decision problem formulations are not equivalent to the problem for which the formulation is made, there are just intermediate paths to translate an NP-complete problem into them (to prove that a problem is NP-hard).

TSP is NP-hard which is completely different to being in NP.

Comment: @fons There was no formulation in the question, so assuming that TSP and Hamiltonian Circuit both referred to the decision problems with those names is just as reasonable as not doing so.

Comment: Oh, I see. That would actually make sense. (otherwise why would you want to translate those two problems). Your assumption is reasonable, maybe we should clarify. Thanks! :) And sorry for the unnecessary lecturing.

Comment: @fons No problem - it is always better to raise an issue if something does not make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian Cycle Problem is proven to be NP-complete (As of today, the best performing algorithm known to solve has exponential complexity),

Also, The Hamiltonian Cycle Problem is a decision problem (Given a graph, Is there is a loop with non-overlapping edges covering all the vertices?) whereas TSP is a search problem (Within all the hamiltonian cycles give me the one with a lower cost).

So .... I don't think that the reduction you are asking for exists (intuitively TSP is more complex) and if it does, I don't think it would help you due to The Hamiltonian Problem being NP-complete (exponential complexity is impractical for large enough problems).

If you just want to solve the TSP, then simply use one of the [known algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms). Some of them are designed to perform reasonably well for a small number of vertices (that might be enough for you).

**Note:** I am assuming that you mean the TSP search problem and the Hamiltonian Cycle decision problem, which might not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Take your graph and remove all the edges. Take an arbitrary vertex v and add back directed edges starting from that vertex if the added edge destination is not further from v than k the length constant from tsp decision problem.

If the constructed graph has a Hamiltonian cycle then it is also a tour of length < k in the original graph, thus a solution to TSP.

Inversely, if there is no hamiltonian cycle in the graph: 
as you have constructed all the paths of length < k starting at the vertex v and as a solution to TSP is a path of length < k starting at v, and a hamiltonian cycle, there is no solution to TSP in the original graph.

Comment: try to explain with images

Answer (score -1):

From Wikipedia's article on the [Hamiltonian path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), might give you a hint:

"The Hamiltonian cycle problem is also a special case of the travelling salesman problem, obtained by setting the distance between two cities to one if they are adjacent and two otherwise, and verifying that the total distance travelled is equal to n (if so, the route is a Hamiltonian circuit; if there is no Hamiltonian circuit then the shortest route will be longer)."

Comment: This reduction is in the wrong direction.  (A very common mistake, BTW...)

Answer (score -1):

Well, the question is what you want to do exactly. Normally, the TSP is about finding the `smallest` way. If you want to find the smallest way, then you can not do it in this way. Only if you have all solution from the Hamilton problem.
Because the Hamilton problem does not care about edge weight, but which is necessary for the salesman.

Example:
Graph A,B,C with A-(10)-B, B-(10)-C, C-(1)-A

Clearly, A->B->C is a Hamilton way, but optimal solution for TSP would be A->C->B

If you just want to find any solution for the TSP, not necessarily the smallest, then you just map the TSP nodes to Hamilton nodes, solve it, go back with the mapping and you are done.

Answer (score -1):

the input instance of TSP is a complete graph and the input instance of Ham_Cycle is an undirected graph G(u,v). Then you transformation function must map the graph G to a complete graph.

---

- Construct a complete graph G' on the same vertices of G with weight
  fn w(u,v)
- w(u,v) = 1 if the edge e(u,v) exists in G
- w(u,v) = INF otherwise
- set the weight k to |V| (number of vi)
- Run the TSP problem on G'

Comment: That's the counter reduction